# is WCF REST Starter Kit no longer the way to go ahead and creat Restful services?

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-rest

maybe the question is so lame but this thing is confusing me a lot. there is a screencast series on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/wcf-screencasts and WCF Starter kit in use there.

But the project was done on .net 3.5 and now I would love to create my restful wcf services on .net 4. when I install the wcf starter kit, the project templates are not on the project list on VS 2010. So, should I use wcf starter kit dll files on my .net projects or not?

The way I am doing now is to add the references manually which comes from wcf starter kit to my project.

Thanks.

Comment: I would highly recommend using .Net's MVC Web API to create a REST web service.

Comment: @Scampbell I know, I wrote a book on it :p + it's called ASP.NET Web API; not MVC Web API ;)

Comment: Wow! Thanks for saving me future embarrassment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The REST Starter kit ended in second preview version and it's not developed any more. You can still use it but it's beta version without any support.

WCF 4 included some parts from starter kit and made REST developement in WCF easier but it still don't have all features from the starter kit. There is also [separate project](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) taking other features from REST Starter Kit and including a lot more. It will probably be part of next major WCF release.

Comment: Yes, http://wcf.codeplex.com is definitely the official future of REST on the Microsoft stack.